# Condition field in atk4 form

Tags: atk4

I am using atk4 Form in my application. I want to show a text field on clicking 'Y' option in a radio field. Is there any build in function to set condition or need jquery script to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, here is the demo-site for older, 3.9 version of Agile Toolkit. The javascript functionality should be compatible with 4.2, but be careful.

http://demo39.agiletoolkit.org/demo.html?t=29

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is bindConditionalShow function supported in latest version?